# class newInstance propagates checked and unchecked exceptions - is it true?

Tags: java

According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorTrouble.html

> Class.newInstance() Throws Unexpected Exception
>   The ConstructorTroubleToo example shows an unresolvable problem in Class.newInstance(). Namely, it propagates any exception — checked or unchecked — thrown by the constructor.
>
> This situation is unique to reflection. Normally, it is impossible to write code which ignores a checked exception because it would not compile. It is possible to wrap any exception thrown by a constructor by using Constructor.newInstance() rather than Class.newInstance().

Below I have a code that doesnt catch any unchecked (RuntimeEcxeption/Error) exception I commented them and it compiles. So where is this propagation? I wrote code that ignores unchecked exceptions which was told to be impossible. Please explain me what is wrong with Class.newInstance() regarding the above quotations?

```
try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("ConstructorTroubleToo");
        // Method propagetes any exception thrown by the constructor
        // (including checked exceptions).

        Object o = c.newInstance();

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
            InstantiationException | 
            IllegalAccessException  x
           /*IllegalArgumentException | 
             SecurityException x*/ ) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`Class.newInstance()` does indeed propagate any exception thrown by the constructor it calls, checked or unchecked.  The propagation is done in a rather underhand way, by calling the method `sun.misc.Unsafe.throwException()`.  This method, which simply throws the exception you give it, is part of the class `sun.misc.Unsafe` which contains various methods for low-level 'unsafe' operations in Java. [This article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe) summarises some of those methods.

In the JDK there is a `src.zip` file, which contains sources to some standard Java platform classes.  In particular, you'll find the source to `java.lang.Class` within the file `java/lang/Class.java` in this zip.  Open up this file and look at the `newInstance()` method within it.  You'll find that `Class.newInstance()` actually uses `Constructor.newInstance()` to create the object.

If a constructor throws an exception, calling the constructor via `Constructor.newInstance()` will wrap the 'real' exception up in an InvocationTargetException and throw that.  However, `Class.newInstance()` isn't declared to throw an InvocationTargetException, so instead it catches the InvocationTargetException thrown by `Constructor.newInstance()` and throws the 'real' exception instead, using `Unsafe.throwException()`.

The reason that `Class.newInstance()` isn't declared to throw InvocationTargetException is because this method dates all the way back to Java 1.0.  InvocationTargetException and the rest of the reflection API was introduced to Java in version 1.1.  Adding `throws InvocationTargetException` to `Class.newInstance()` would have broken backwards compatibility when compiling Java 1.0 code with Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Propagation means that exception just goes out unlike wrapping into InvocationTargetException like reflection methods normally behave.

Actually it's not that impossible to write a code which ignores checked exception. Consider the first case from [here](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/11/03/10-things-you-didnt-know-about-java/):

```
public class Test {
    // No throws clause here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThrow(new SQLException());
    }

    static void doThrow(Exception e) {
        Test.<RuntimeException> doThrow0(e);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <E extends Exception> 
    void doThrow0(Exception e) throws E {
        throw (E) e;
    }
}
```

JVM does not distinguish checked and unchecked exceptions and there are some ways to fool the Java compiler.

Comment: Nice trick but referring to the quotations, why it they say, that it is "an unresolvable problem" that class.newInstance() "propagates any exception — checked or unchecked — thrown by the constructor" ? This is exactly how other methods works, if they throw RuntimeException we dont catch it, if it is checkedException we catch it and what is wrong with that ? How they would like it to work?

Comment: I think I see it now, in some construtor i throw new Exception();, normally I wouldnt write new class with such constructor without try+catch, class.newInstance hides this exception and I cant even catch it, constructor.newInstance wraps is into InvocationTargetException, so it is better than class.newInstace as I can control this situation. Is that right or there is something more?